# Predicting stationarity of a time series

Tags: time-series, predictive-models, stochastic-processes, stationarity

I have a time series, for example equity prices. This series is weakly stationary (for instance an AR process that does not violate the stability condition). How can I make predictions on how likely it is that this series will stay weakly stationary?

Is there maybe an approach that states, conditional on the past, the time series will stay stationary if it has been for a long time stationary in the past?